# Extract certain numbers from string

Tags: r, regex

Given the following vector:

```
v = c("A/5 21171", "PC 175959", "STON/O2. 3101282", "113803", "373450")
```

How can extract the last 5 or 6 digits from each element? This the **desired output**:

```
v_processed = c("21171", "175959", "3101282", "113803", "373450")
```

My try:

```
v = unlist(strsplit(v, "^[^0-9]+"))
v[v == ""] = NA
v_processed = na.omit(v)
```

But that last snippet gives me this:

```
"5 21171"    "175959"     "2. 3101282" "113803"     "373450"
```

I do not want that 5 in the first element, nor the "2." in the third one.

Thx.

Comment: Wait, `3101282` is 7 digits. And try `sub(".*?(\\d{5,6})$", "\\1", v)` (if you want `101282` in fact, not `3101282`)

Comment: You are right. `3101282` is 7 digits. Then I refer to the last bunch of digits, no matter they are 5, 6 or 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
> sub(".*\\b(\\d+)$", "\\1", v)
[1] "21171"   "175959"  "3101282" "113803"  "373450"
```

Here, `.*\\b` matches all the chars up to the last leading word boundary and grabs 1+ digits at the end of the string with `(\\d+)$` into Group 1.

Or, if the digits are preceded with whitespace:

```
> sub(".*\\s(\\d+)$", "\\1", v)
[1] "21171"   "175959"  "3101282" "113803"  "373450"
```

where `.*\\s` matches the string up to the last whitespace.

Alternatively, use a matching approach. Here is how you may extract 1+ digits (as a whole word) at the end of the string:

```
> regmatches(v, regexpr("\\b\\d+$", v))
[1] "21171"   "175959"  "3101282" "113803"  "373450"
```

Or extract them only if they are preceded with whitespace:

```
> regmatches(v, regexpr("(?<!\\S)\\d+$", v, perl=TRUE))
[1] "21171"   "175959"  "3101282" "113803"  "373450"
```

Here, a PCRE regex (see `perl=TRUE`) is used to simplify the code. The `(?<!\\S)` is a negative lookbehind that makes sure there is no non-whitespace symbol immediately to the left of the current location.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `substring`

```
substring(v, nchar(v)-c(4, 5, 6, 5, 5), nchar(v))
#[1] "21171"   "175959"  "3101282" "113803"  "373450"
```

---

Or with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(v, "\\d+$")
#[1] "21171"   "175959"  "3101282" "113803"  "373450"
```